# Angular 6 Dependency Injection when a page opens in a "new" window (target="-blank")

Tags: angular

I have a service that needs to be shared between 2 components ( unrelated). There are 3 components - Landing Component, Component X and Component Y. Initial page is landing page and using 2 links, user can go to Page X served by component X or Page Y served by component Y. When the user clicks the links, I have target="_blank" and hence the page opens in a new window. Component X uses the service (dependency injection of the service) and puts some data and that data is to be used by the component Y when Page Y link is clicked. Component Y has dependency injection of the same service in it's constructor.

If all the pages are in the SAME window, then everything works as expected. Component Y gets the same exact instance of the service that Component X filled in the data.

However. as soon as I put in target="_blank", the 2 components have 2 different instances of the service when using Dependency Injection.

Is there any way to tell Angular NOT to create a new instance of the Service when used in a new window ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am quite sure that when you open app in new tab or window, it is a different instance of that app, so this won't work. The only think that persists between windows/tabs is browser _storage_, so you could try using that approach... Maybe someone else knows bit more about this...

Comment: Very Good, thanks, I was hoping to hear very similar and thanks so much for confirming the behavior. So the question is about the design - what do most designers do when they are "required" to open new windows and still share data between different components ? I thought about optional route parametrs, but they appear on URL and hence security issue, thought about using files and the issue is same (security), Even global data is "brand new" when you open up in a new window. So, I am kind of questioning if designers allow the "new window" or they just work with "TABS" in the "same window" ?

Comment: as mentioned before - localStorage or sessionStorage is the solution to that issue. that's what "designers" most likely will use ;) alternatively you can of course also fetch & store data on your server via an api.

Comment: I think you can send data through browser's _local storage_ (put in LS and remove from LS) and receive in another window.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, server is another option, but would like to avoid it since it may increase the load to the server. Are there any good links to describe how to put and get the data into browser's local storage ? I will search for the same.